# Creating sublists

Tags: python, list, grouping

The opposite of list flattening.

Given a list and a length n return a list of sub lists of length n.

```
def sublist(lst, n):
    sub=[] ; result=[]
    for i in lst:
        sub+=[i]
        if len(sub)==n: result+=[sub] ; sub=[]
    if sub: result+=[sub]
    return result
```

An example:

If the list is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

And n is:

```
3
```

Return:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Is there a more eloquent / concise way?

An aside, what is preferred when appending lists to lists (in the context above):

```
list1+=[list2]
```

Or:

```
list1.append(list2)
```

Given that (according to Summerfeild's 'Programming in Python 3') they are the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Such a list of lists could be constructed using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [17]: seq=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
In [18]: [seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(seq),3)]
Out[18]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

There is also the [grouper idiom](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
In [19]: import itertools
In [20]: list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(seq)]*3))
Out[20]: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, None)]
```

but note that missing elements are filled with the value None. [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) can take a `fillvalue` parameter as well if something other than None is desired.

---

`list1+=[list2]` -- noting the brackets this time -- is equivalent to `list1.append(list2)`. My highest priority when writing code is readability, 
not speed. For this reason, I would go with `list1.append(list2)`. Readability is subjective, however, and probably is influenced greatly by what idioms you're familiar with.

Happily, in this case, readability and speed seem to coincide:

```
In [41]: %timeit list1=[1,2,3]; list1.append(list2)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 612 ns per loop

In [42]: %timeit list1=[1,2,3]; list1+=[list2]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 847 ns per loop
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu, have to laugh how trivial this is using the list comprehension. Underscores my need to study them. Regarding += vs append, I understand the difference, noting I compared list1+=[list2] to list1.append(list2), not list1+=list2 and list1.append(list2). Thanks great answer / discussion.

Comment: @Michael Puckett: Oops, I misread the second part of your question. Editing...

Comment: Thanks unutbu -- append ftw. :)

Answer (score 11):

How about the following (where `x` is your list):

```
 [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
```

This is trivial to generalize for `n!=3`.

As to your second question, they're equivalent so I think it's a matter of style. However, do make sure you're not [confusing `append` with `extend`](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/899_Python-extend-v-append-on-a-list.html).

Comment: Thanks aix, list comprehension definitely the way to go. I'm chagrined I didn't think of it but take comfort in the fact I'm a python noob.

Answer (score 10):

Have you heard of [`boltons`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io)?

> **`Boltons`** is a set of pure-Python utilities in the same spirit as — and yet conspicuously missing from — the the standard library

It has what you want, built-in, called [`chunked`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#boltons.iterutils.chunked)

```
from boltons import iterutils

iterutils.chunked([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

And whats *more attractive* in `boltons` is that it has `chunked` as an **iterator**, called [`chunked_iter`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#boltons.iterutils.chunked_iter), so you don't need to store the whole thing in memory. Neat, right?

Answer (score 7):

This function can take any kind of iterable (not only sequences of known length):

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, it):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ABC DEF G"
    it = iter(it)
    return iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(it, n)), [])

print(list(grouper(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])))
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this split function does what you're looking for (though it works with any iterator rather than just lists):

```
from itertools import islice

def take(n, it):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(it, n))

def split(it, size):
    it = iter(it)
    size = int(size)
    ret = take(size, it)
    while ret:
        yield ret
        ret = take(size, it)
```

Edit: Regarding your asside, I always use list.append(blah), as it feels more idiomatic to me, but I believe they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: the django things doesn't look necessary

Comment: @Xavier yup, i've removed it (i was originally using this as a django template filter)

Answer (score 1):

For some specific cases, it might be useful to use the numpy package. In this package you have a [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) routine:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
np.reshape(x, (-1,3))
```

However, this solution won't pad your list, if it's not a multiply of n.

Comment: Numpy is kinda overkill for this. HOWEVER, it's good to know about the noted functionality. Thank you joker5.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it looks like a [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), but is works:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>>> n = 3
>>> [i for j in [[a[t:t+n] for x in a[:1:t+1] if (t%n)==False] for t in range(len(a))] for i in j]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]

>>> n = 4
>>> [i for j in [[a[t:t+n] for x in a[:1:t+1] if (t%n)==False] for t in range(len(a))] for i in j]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```