# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable BUT works in IDLE

Tags: python

The following portion of code works in the IDLE console but outputs an error when run inside a .py script. Therefore I cannot understand the reason.

```
[results[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(results),3)]
```

where results is defined as the following :

```
results = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

In the IDLE no error prompted :

```
>>> results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [results[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(results),3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

My idea behind was to group part of a list into a sublist as suggested here: [Creating sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501636/creating-sublists)

Thanks !

Comment: which error are you getting? I tried executing the same with .py file and it is working just fine.

Comment: A better title would be "Code works interactively but fails when in a .py file".  You would have gotten the same results if you entered the two lines in the Python console and ran the file with a previous rebinding of `range` from the IDLE editor.  In other words, the use of IDLE is irrelevant to the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine on its own.

```
>>> results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [results[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(results),3)]
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You probably assigned the name `range` or `len` to a list somewhere and thereby shadow the built in `range` or `len` callable.

```
>>> range = [] # don't reassign names of builtins!
>>> results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [results[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(results),3)]
[...]
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The error occurs because Python is trying to do `[](0,len(results))` here.

Comment: That's it ! A list named 'range' was indeed declared in another part of the code and I did not pay attention. Thank you very much for your clear and fast reply