# Single vector multiple times in 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.6

This is my code:

```
b = [6 * [1, 3, 4, 2],
 4 * [2, 1, 4, 3],
 3 * [3, 4, 2, 1],
 4 * [4, 2, 1, 3],
 4 * [4, 3, 2, 1],
 ]
```

Which returns an array which has 6X4=24 elements in the first line 4X4=16 in the second etc...

What i want to achieve is adding the exact same line multiple times like:

```
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 4, 2
1, 3, 4, 2 #6 tines the first line
2, 1, 4, 3
2, 1, 4, 3
2, 1, 4, 3
2, 1, 4, 3 # 4 times the second
..........
```

but of course by not copying the same line again and again

Comment: This is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501636/creating-sublists

Comment: Thanks, even though this has 69 answers already i didn't find it before (probably because of my bad english), but i got the answer i wanted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also put it in one line with

```
b = 6*[[1, 3, 4, 2]] + 4*[[2, 1, 4, 3]] + 3*[[3, 4, 2, 1]] + 4*[[4, 2, 1, 3]] + 4* [[4, 3, 2, 1]])

print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
b = [
    *[[1, 3, 4, 2] for _ in range(6)],
    *[[2, 1, 4, 3] for _ in range(4)],
    *[[3, 4, 2, 1] for _ in range(3)],
    *[[4, 2, 1, 3] for _ in range(4)],
    *[[4, 3, 2, 1] for _ in range(4)],
]

print(b)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [1, 3, 4, 2],
    [1, 3, 4, 2],
    [1, 3, 4, 2],
    [1, 3, 4, 2],
    [1, 3, 4, 2],
    [1, 3, 4, 2],
    [2, 1, 4, 3],
    [2, 1, 4, 3],
    [2, 1, 4, 3],
    [2, 1, 4, 3],
    [3, 4, 2, 1],
    [3, 4, 2, 1],
    [3, 4, 2, 1],
    [4, 2, 1, 3],
    [4, 2, 1, 3],
    [4, 2, 1, 3],
    [4, 2, 1, 3],
    [4, 3, 2, 1],
    [4, 3, 2, 1],
    [4, 3, 2, 1],
    [4, 3, 2, 1],
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but the other one is faster that's why i gave it the check,but yours is upvoted too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only two steps if you don't want to change how `b` was created.

```
import numpy as np 

B = np.concatenate(b).ravel()
b = np.reshape(B,(21,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension of a list comprehension to repeat `y` times your `x` lists (from `bb` and `aa`, respectively)

The notation is a bit strange, the "center" one is the outer element, then it expands on the right.

Advantage: numpy not required, and it will work for any size entries, unlike other answers "harcoding" the rows

```
aa=[[1, 3, 4, 2],
[2, 1, 4, 3],
[3, 4, 2, 1],
[4, 2, 1, 3],
[4, 3, 2, 1]]

bb=[6,4,3,4,4]

xx = [x for x,y in zip(aa,bb) for _ in range(y) ]
```

returns:
[[1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 3, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 4, 3], [3, 4, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done systematically by pairing the factors and the sublists and multiplying them together. Then flat the list.

Here a hacky-way

```
b = [[1, 3, 4, 2],
 [2, 1, 4, 3],
 [3, 4, 2, 1],
 [4, 2, 1, 3],
 [4, 3, 2, 1],
 ]

factors = [6, 4, 3, 4, 4]

print(sum(f*[l] for f, l in zip(factors, b), []))
```

The flattening part (chaining of lists) is done with `sum( , [])` but is **not** performant (and designed for that)... but still useful, in my opinion, to test some small stuffs on the fly. The list chaining **have to be done** with i.e. `itertools.chain`. Here an example

```
import itertools as it
...
list(it.chain.from_iterable(f*[l] for f, l in zip(factors, b)))

# or (for many iterators)
list(it.chain(*(f*[l] for f, l in zip(factors, b))))

# or with repeat
list(it.chain.from_iterable(it.starmap(it.repeat, zip(b, factors))))

# or (another) with repeat
list(it.chain.from_iterable(map(it.repeat, b, factors))

# or ...
list(it.chain.from_iterable(map(list.__mul__, ([i] for i in b) , factors)))

# or with reduce
import functools as fc

list(fc.reduce(lambda i, j: i + j, zip(b, factors)))
```